# problem in \def with if

Tags: definition

I would like to make a definition in the form:

```
\def\nameMYdef#1{
if (length of text #1) <= (width of the text on the page (? \textwidth ?) ) 
then (center(#1))
else ( justification(#1))
}
```

Of course, this entry is only symbolic. I hope that it is understandable.

Best regards and I am looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Some definitional adjustments may be needed depending on how you want indents to be handled, and whether invocation is allowed NOT at the beginning of a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\nameMYdef#1{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}\ifdim\wd0<\linewidth\relax\centerline{#1}\else #1\fi}
\begin{document}
\nameMYdef{Test of short line}

\nameMYdef{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it works! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Maniek The logic is straightforward.  It sets the content provided in `\box0`, and measures the width (`\wd`) of the box `0`, comparing it to the allotted `\linewidth`.  If it is less, use `\centerline`, otherwise, just set the multiline text as is.